# Change the parent of a view

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I have a table view that i would display at some point after I get some results from the database

```
@IBOutlet weak var resultSetView: UITableView!
```

I this table view is already made in the ViewController

I would like to put this element in another view like a dock view maybe programmatically. Depending on my requirement. 
In a different case, maybe I would like to place it in another location.

How do I do that?

Comment: Why don't  you just set up the storyboard how you want it...?

Comment: Because it a view sits there and it needs to be programmatically populated with different button clicks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
 @IBOutlet weak var resultSetView: UITableView!
 @IBOutlet weak var nestedDockView: UIView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    nestedDockView.addSubview(resultSetView);


}
```

Comment: Try this if you want to do it programmatically. Although personally I would just drag one view under the other in the document outline inside of xcode. If you want it hidden or just to show up later you can do that in code as well, but again I prefer the attributes inspector for that.

Comment: The idea is to have a different kinds of views inside this "nestedDockView". Which is why i requested for an input on programmatic implementation. Will try it out and let you know how it goes. Thank you very much Antonio

Comment: That worked Antonio. Thank you. Also, is there a way I could set the constraints to fill 100% of the nestedDockView every time no matter the dimensions of the nestedDockVIew

Comment: Just found out something. It works for views created in the controller code but not for a view that is already created and has a connector in code. Is there a work around for this?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your tableView is retained. You can easily do this:

[tableView removeFromSuperview];

[dockView addSubview:tableView];

When doing this, beware:

When you reparent the view, it will inherit new layout constraint from the new parent which can be different from original view.

If you are thinking to reparent this across VC, it should work but it's really messy in terms of s/w design and encapsulation.

Comment: When i try to reparent the view, the view doesn't add into the dock view. Is there anything specific I need to do for this?

Comment: Is this in the same VC? Have you remove tableView? Make sure tableView is retained.